# Conditional exclusion of installed file in CMake

Tags: installation, cmake, generator-expression

I need to exclude a file when installing directory in CMake if the condition is met. So I need something like this:

```
install(
    DIRECTORY include
    COMPONENT dev
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    PATTERN $<$<NOT:$<STREQUAL:${MY_VAR},SOME_VALUE>>:my_header.h> EXCLUDE
)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generator expressions are not available in `install()` rules. But since yours doesn't actually depend on any generator-time information, anyway, you can use CMake's argument expansion to accomplish this.

```
if (MY_VAR STREQUAL "SOME_VALUE")
    set(exclusion_patterns "")
else ()
    set(exclusion_patterns PATTERN my_header.h EXCLUDE)
endif ()

install(
    DIRECTORY include
    COMPONENT dev
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    ${exclusion_patterns}
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I also thought about `if...else` statement, but hoped to make generator expressions work, as they are a little more compact